# Kubuntu on XPS 15 does not recognize power disconnect

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, dell, power-management, xps

I installed Kubuntu 22 on Dell XPS 15 9520 and the laptop will not recognizes when I disconnect the power cable. It only reads "connected but not charging". So now It happned multiple times that I was not notified about low battery and drained it all the way until the laptop shut down - which isn't good for battery life.

I tried calling `acpi_listen` on the console and the power disconnect events are actually sent by the kernel.

```
ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000000
battery PNP0C0A:00 00000080 00000001
```

Calling `sudo journalctl  --follow` does not show anything when connecting or disconnecting the power cable.

Calling `upower -d` shows the following output:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wed Jan 24 08:45:15 2024 (5414 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               BYD
  model:                DELL M59JH25
  serial:               879
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wed Jan 24 10:15:14 2024 (15 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              83.0832 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         83.0832 Wh
    energy-full-design:  84.2916 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0114 W
    voltage:             12.67 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          100%
    temperature:         26.7 degrees C
    capacity:            98.5664%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o001
  native-path:          ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:001
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wed Jan 24 08:45:15 2024 (5414 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o002
  native-path:          ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:002
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wed Jan 24 08:45:15 2024 (5414 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o003
  native-path:          ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:003
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wed Jan 24 08:45:15 2024 (5414 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/mouse_[...]
  native-path:          /org/bluez/hci0/[...]
  model:                [...]
  serial:               [...]
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed Jan 24 08:45:25 2024 (5404 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  mouse
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        no
    state:               unknown
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          64%
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/keyboard_[...]
  native-path:          /org/bluez/hci0/[...]
  model:                [...]
  serial:               [...]
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed Jan 24 08:47:21 2024 (5288 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  keyboard
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        no
    state:               unknown
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          90%
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wed Jan 24 08:45:14 2024 (5415 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              83.0832 Wh
    energy-full:         83.0832 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0114 W
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.17
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: PowerOff
```

Any ideas how to make it recognize power disconnect?

Comment: What does `upower -d` show?

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you unplug the power.

Comment: @waltinator `sudo journalctl  --follow` does not show anything when connecting or disconnecting.

Comment: @DanielT I added the output to the question.

Comment: "battery_BAT0 state: fully-charged percentage: 100% icon-name: 'battery-full-charged-symbolic'" suggests the backend is fine. Note that at 100% the battery icon normally moves from the taskbar into the panel you see after clicking the arrow. Verif you didn't disable the sound. If the icon is missing, you may have forgotten to install a package, idk which, so try `apt install kde-full`

Comment: @DanielT this is wonderful: reinstalling `kde-full` worked. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: @DanielT I have another problem, that might be caused by something similar but has not been fixed: I changed something on my audio packages and since then my audio devices are not recognized on startup anymore. Once I call `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio` everything works. Do you have an idea, how can I make Kubuntu recognize my audio devices on startup again?

Comment: @EricXyz Idk really. I'm on 23.10, after the 22.10 PipeWire migration. I did set an autostart to play an empty audio file on startup, but that probably won't solve your problem. Please ask another question including the `journalctl --user` so that someone else can help you.

Comment: @DanielT I will do that and ask another question. Thanks, a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the GUI that displays the battery indicator. Do `sudo apt install kde-full` or the specific package to fix this problem.

As you wrote in your question, the kernel and backend are not the problem. ACPI is correctly getting the message. upower is properly reporting the current status of the device `battery_BAT0` as `percentage: 100%` and `icon-name: 'battery-full-charged-symbolic'`.

Therefore the problem lies in your userland desktop environment. There is usually a sound when you plug and unplug the power cord, so make sure you did not disable that. The taskbar battery indicator hides and unhides itself when it gets to 100%, so click on the `^` icon to unhide it.

The battery status indicator applet itself is provided by the package `plasma-workspace-data` so it shouldn't be the missing one. However, it gets its data from KDE's power management daemon, PowerDevil. A minimal KDE install might not include this package, and if you don't want to install all of KDE, you could try just installing `kde-plasma-desktop` instead and relog.